# Minimum and Maximum Count of Overlapping Bookings

Tags: mysql, date

I have a booking system that has multiple simultaneous bookings with a count number for each. I need to get the minimum and maximum for a specified date-range (for a day, in this case). I found some good code [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae213/59), which works great in the test. But in my implementation, it fails in this particular instance:

- It does not count bookings that start prior to the query-range and end within the query-range.

How do I fix this?

Here is an example:

This booking exists with these properties:
listings (an ID that multiple bookings can have, but only one in this case): 2f23f23f

date_start: 2016-01-15 08:00:00

date_end: 2016-01-17 08:00:00

state: active

count: 1

Result:

min_count: 0

max_count: 0

It should return:

min_count: 0

max_count: 1

If we query the very same, but with date range 2016-01-16 00:00:00 - 2016-01-16 23:59:59, it returns the correct answer:

min_count: 1

max_count: 1

Here is the MYSQL:

```
SELECT
    MAX(simultaneous) AS max_count,
    MIN(simultaneous) AS min_count
FROM (
  SELECT IFNULL(SUM(
      (
          CASE WHEN (
                listings = '2f23f23f'
                AND 
                    (state = 'active')
          )
          THEN count
          ELSE 0
          END
      )
    ),0) AS simultaneous
  FROM   bookings RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT date_start AS boundary
    FROM   bookings
    WHERE date_start BETWEEN '2016-01-17 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-17 23:59:59'

  UNION
    SELECT date_end
    FROM   bookings
    WHERE  date_end BETWEEN '2016-01-17 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-17 23:59:59'

  UNION
    SELECT MAX(boundary)
    FROM (
      SELECT MAX(date_start) AS boundary
      FROM   bookings
      WHERE date_start <= '2016-01-17 00:00:00'

    UNION ALL
      SELECT MAX(date_end)
      FROM   bookings
      WHERE date_end <= '2016-01-17 23:59:59'

    ) t
  ) t ON date_start <= boundary AND boundary < date_end
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cart ON cart_bookings = id
  GROUP BY boundary
) t
```

Comment: Event b overlaps event a if event b starts before event a ends and ends after event a starts.

Comment: Your comment got me thinking on the right lines, I think. The inner select was obtaining only the "boundary" - which was only a single result, which failed to return because of the < instead of <=. Changing that still didn't solve the problem of there being only one returning date to test instead of two (min/max). Forcing it to consider the beginning and end of the time-range seems to have solved the problem per below.

Comment: It *looks* like an overly long (and potentially incomplete) answer to me - but, hey, if it works for you then that's all that matters, right? If you decide you need further help with this then you really need to consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements, and a desired result.

Comment: SQL is not my speciality and I've never had a good prototyping flow. This time I used sqlfiddle.com some, but it's miserably slow. Next time I'll package up a better question. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whew, ok, here's the answer. The original evidently wasn't complete. It needed to include the start/end dates of the time-range being requested.

```
  UNION
    SELECT :date_start
  UNION
    SELECT :date_end
```

Complete code:

```
SELECT
    MAX(simultaneous) AS max_count,
    MIN(simultaneous) AS min_count
FROM (
  SELECT IFNULL(SUM(
      (
          CASE WHEN (
                listings = '2f23f23f'
                AND 
                    (state = 'active')
          )
          THEN count
          ELSE 0
          END
      )
    ),0) AS simultaneous
  FROM   bookings RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT date_start AS boundary
    FROM   bookings
    WHERE date_start BETWEEN '2016-01-17 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-17 23:59:59'

  UNION
    SELECT date_end
    FROM   bookings
    WHERE  date_end BETWEEN '2016-01-17 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-17 23:59:59'

  UNION
    SELECT MAX(boundary)
    FROM (
      SELECT MAX(date_start) AS boundary
      FROM   bookings
      WHERE date_start <= '2016-01-17 00:00:00'

    UNION ALL
      SELECT MAX(date_end)
      FROM   bookings
      WHERE date_end <= '2016-01-17 23:59:59'

    ) t
  UNION
    SELECT :date_start
  UNION
    SELECT :date_end
  ) t ON date_start <= boundary AND boundary < date_end
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cart ON cart_bookings = id
  GROUP BY boundary
) t
```